# Build Task causing error - Conversion from string "Build Tasks" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: build, msbuild, type-conversion

I am working on some code that I inherited. This is my first try at building it and I get the following error:

```
Error   1   Conversion from string "Build Tasks" to type 'Integer' is not valid.    C:\Users\PatTrain15\Desktop\Plugin Sources\PAT_SubscriptionDatePlugin__c\SubscriptionDatePlugin__c.vbproj   157 5   SubscriptionDatePlugin__c
```

Here are lines 156 - 158 of the .vbproj file in question.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<IncrementBuildNumber AssemblyFileLocation="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb" />
</Target>
```

There is a BuildTask.dll file in the root of the project.

I dont really have any idea how to proceed to eliminate this error from the project.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on here?

Thank you.

Comment: Start by collecting verbose logging from msbuild. The option is `/v:d` on msbuild command line. Usually examination of detailed logs helps. If it does not, add relevant section from detailed traces to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this too - in my old 2010 project, I was manipulating the build numbers, incrementing them to a set schedule.  I did this by setting before and after build steps.

In my 2012 project, I did not see the changes in the before and after steps even though the code was still in the xml in the csproj file.

Solution: I removed the build.dll and incrementbuild steps (remember to remove the end tags too) from the csproj file and my project successfully built under VS 2012.

I'll be looking at the new features in publish where I can exercise control over my versioning info with greater granularity.

Hope this helps-